# I want to create setup file with Inno Setup

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I need help with Inno Setup. First of all I want to sorry about my english. I hope you understand me.

I have this script:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "My software - BETA"
#define MyAppVersion "1.5"
#define MyAppExeName "My software.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{009E8058-565E-43F7-BEAD-34E283BCA6F4}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
DefaultDirName={pf}\{#MyAppName}
DefaultGroupName={#MyAppName}
LicenseFile=D:\My software\EULA.rtf
OutputBaseFilename=My software - Setup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "D:\My software\My software.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "D:\My software\settings.txt"; DestDir: "{userappdata}\My software"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,{#MyAppName}}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

The setup works but I want to add several options to the setup:

1) If the software is already installed then I want that will be an option that give the usere the ability to choose whether to overwrite the previous settings..
something like checkbox: "Don't overwrite the previous settings"
and in by default the setup will not overwrite the previous settings.

2) In the uninstaller I want the option: "Remove also the settings" (something like that) and by default this option is unchecked

3) I want that the option "Create a desktop icon" will always be checked by default.
I noticed that this option is checked by default only if the icon is already created before.

Thanks for helpers!
Gil.

Answer (score 0):

### **Answers for your question:**

**1-If you are installing a application which is already install it should give user uninstalling
 option.To keep Previous setting you can use `Flags: onlyifdoesntexist` for `[Files]`, or**

**`Flags: createvalueifdoesntexist` for `[Registry]`.**

**2-Put the following `code` in `[Code]` section,it should give user to removeing setting option.**

```
[Code]
procedure CurUninstallStepChanged (CurUninstallStep: TUninstallStep);
var
  mres : integer;
begin
  case CurUninstallStep of
    usPostUninstall:
      begin
        mres := MsgBox('Do you want to Remove Settings?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO or MB_DEFBUTTON2)
        if mres = IDYES then
          DelTree(ExpandConstant('{userdocs}\Myapp'), True, True, True);
      end;
  end;
end;
```

**3-If you want the icon task Will be checked then remove the `Flags: unchecked` part from `[Task]` section.**

Comment: 1) why would it be so ? Inno Setup is capable of automatic updates without uninstalling previous version. To preserve settings, you use `onlyifdoesntexist` flag for `[Files]`, or `createvalueifdoesntexist` for `[Registry]`.

Comment: @Tlama Thanks for the hint i will add them.